# How is the "Soldiers" demographic in Civ 5 calculated?

Tags: civilization-5

Pretty simple question. In the Demographics window a bunch of information about your Civ is listed, including a "Soldiers" number that indicates your military strength. How is it calculated? I'm guessing it's not a simple answer because I've noticed a few things about the number, although I've never examined it very scientifically:

- It seems that melee units will increase your "Soldiers" count more than ranged units. This might mean that the value is calculated based on the units' Combat Strength not Ranged Strength. I've had games where I've had many ranged units and the computers have had only a few melee units and they still are ranked has having more "Soldiers".
- The "Soldiers" count depends on the state of your units. It appears that damaged units count less towards the total number. Furthermore it appears that units count for more while Fortified. No clue whether or not unit promotions factor in to this as well.
- The "Soldiers" count does not increase linearly with the number of units you have. I literally just found this out. Playing a conquest game I just started buying units to spend the giant surplus I had built up, to see if I could reach a Soldier count of 1 000 000. I noticed that, even though I was buying more units (and none of my other units were damaged or moving) my Soldier count was *decreasing*!

So does anyone know the exact formula for how this number is calculated? Is it relative to the other Civs in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is rather simple: `2000*n^0.5`

Now, it is not so very obvious (or known) how n is calculated, however this seems to be the basic formula (it somewhat matches the curve with only a few slight deviations): `(1.15 * combat strength) ^ 1.5`

Mind you, this does take into account damaged units.

There are additional percent modifiers for some subset of innate promotions, which weren't figured out exactly. for example the Jaguar and Mohawk warrior both start at 25% higher than their counterparts, an anti tank gun starts at 25% above it's base 222 (277), while an anti aircraft gun starts at 95% above (432).

Now, there is a more accurate formula which I however didn't test yet myself, for reasons of complexity. Anyway, here you go:

[image]

You have to click it to properly read it, I couldn't really have made it any bigger due to how long it is.

[Source](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/soldiers-rating-in-demographics.442365)